# HTML and CSS Horizontal List

Tags: html, css, inline

I am trying to create a navigation bar that is horizontal although display:inline-block; isnt working for me. On Google Chrome and IE it still appears vertically.

This is my HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Clowning Around</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <div id="header">
          <div class="wrap">
               <div class="logo">
                    !# insert logo picture
               </div>
    <div id ="content">
               <ul id="nav">
                        <li><a href="/home/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/about/">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/news/">News & Events</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/classes/">Classes & Camps</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/gallery/">Gallery</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/contact/">Contact us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/enrol/">Enrol Now</a></li>
                </ul>
          </div>
```

This is my CSS

```
#content {
   width: 40em;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 40px 0; 
}

ul#nav {
    position: absolute;
    right: 50%; 
    left: 50%;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}

ul#nav li a {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 5px 3px 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background-color: #034a7f; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    padding: .2em 1em;
```

Comment: You should give your UL a width, and/or a negative horizontal margin. Right now it's zero wide which is why the browser decides to wrap after each LI.

Comment: @user3487529 if one of the answers you get is working please mark it as the accepted answer. If they don't fit your needs please comment bellow the answer to let the users know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this css :

```
#content {
   width: 40em;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 40px 0; 
}

ul#nav {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}

ul#nav li  {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 5px 3px 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background-color: #034a7f; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    padding: .2em 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to set `float:left;` to the `<li>`

http://jsfiddle.net/ySE2V/

```
ul#nav li {
    float: left;
}
ul#nav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 5px 3px 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background-color: #034a7f; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    padding: .2em 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ul
{
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
li
{
  float:left;
}
a
{
  display:block;
  padding: 8px 5px 3px 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background-color: #034a7f; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bWTwL/1166/)

```
#content {
  width: 50em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px 0; 
}

ul#nav {

  right: 50%; 
  left: 50%;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

}
```